# Internalization and SpringMVC 4.0

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, controller

I'm new to `SpringMVC (4.0)` and I'm working on a bilingual application.

I have an header where you can select between two languages. The URL looks like this: `http://localhost:8080/applicationName/something/edit?id=1`

Is there anyway to keep the params `?id=1` and add `&lang=en?` and if I have an URL like this, `http://localhost:8080/applicationName/something/edit?id=1&lang=en`, is there a way to just modify the value of the params `"lang"`?

Currently, in my jsp, I'm using something like this:

```
<a href="?lang=en"><spring:message code="english" /></a>
```

but as you can see, it won't keep the params `"id"`.

Can I add a controller (only for my header) to build the URL and pass it by parameters to my jsp? Should I use JSTL to do this?

I hope you guys understand my question and sorry for my English! :)